# Using AspNetSqlMembershipProvider in MVC5

Tags: web-config, asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-5

working with MVC5 and trying to integrate **AspNetSqlMembershipProvider** than the default provider or simple membership provider.

Is that possible to use **AspNetSqlMembershipProvider** with **MVC5**? All login and register codes looks clumsy and I am not able to figure out what exactly **UserManager**. I did all necessary alterations in the web.config level, still my users are not validating with the SQL Database which we have created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AspNetSqlMembershipProvider is deprecated.

[ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) is an updated version of ASP.Net Membership Provider.

> Is that possible to use AspNetSqlMembershipProvider with MVC5?

Yes you can use **ASP.NET Universal Providers** in MVC5. If you have used ASP.Net Membership Provider in WebForm previously, they basically are same except you cannot get Async and Await.

> All login and register codes looks clumsy and I am not able to figure
>   out what exactly UserManager.

You do not need to use UserManager which is used by ASP.net Identity.

Comment: MVC4 uses SimpleMembershipProvider so you'll still see Models and Views. **MVC3** uses ASP.NET Universal Providers which is basically same as AspNetSqlMembershipProvider. So you need to create Blank MVC5 Project, then copy those Membership codes from MVC3 to MVC5.